# How can I express the minimization of the p90th percentile mathematically?

Tags: probability-theory, optimization

I would like to minimize the 90th percentile of a function with a normally distributed variable.

If I wanted to minimize the expected value, I would do it something like this:

$$
min_s \ z = E(f(X,s))
$$
where:

X is normally distributed with a fixed distribution

s is the design parameter vector

E is the expected value

How can I express the minimization of the 90th percentile of $E(f(X))$?

Comment: Are you given anything about the mean and standard deviation of $X$?

Comment: Yes. I use several different values for those parameters.

Comment: The notation isn't clear at all, unfortunately. Sure, you want to minimize $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$. But as I'm sure you know, $X$ is dependent on a mean and a standard deviation. Do you want to express that the mean and standard deviation are such that the 90th percentile is minimized? $\min(z) = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ honestly makes no sense. Or if you just want to minimize the 90th percentile, you could just say $\min_{\mu, \sigma}\pi_{0.9}$ where $\mathbb{P}(X \leq \pi_{0.9}) = 0.9$.

Comment: the parameters of the normally distributed variable are not design parameters. I updated my question to include design parameters.

Comment: What are the P and E operators you used? Are these common symbols in the math community?

Comment: Probability, expected value

Comment: How did you make these symbols? What are they called?

Comment: The code is `\mathbb{P}` and `\mathbb{E}` respectively. I don't think there are names beyond the LaTeX code for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\alpha$ quantile of a random variable $X$ is the solution of the following minimisation problem:
$$ \min_u \mathbb{E}\left[\rho_\alpha(X - u)\right]$$ 
where $\rho_\alpha(x)$ is the $\alpha$-hinge loss function
$$ \rho_\alpha(x)=\lvert x(\alpha - \mathbb{I}_{\{x<0\}})\rvert.$$ 
Here $\mathbb{I}_{\{x<0\}}$ is the indicator function which is one if $x<0$ and zero elsewhere. You can find more details and further explanation in the Wikipedia article about [Quantile Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) or any textbook this topic.